# linphone SIP message loss

Tags: android, sip, linphone

We are using liblinphone 2.5.2 in our android project and experiencing an issue with it. liblinphone not receiving SIP messages: according to tcpdump from android device SIP packet is delivered to device interface, but either not processed by liblinphone or processed with 20sec delay.
If anyone have faced such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade linphone to 3.1 version, it fixes the issue.